# What are the things you can grow a shrub/tree/vine from? Only nuts and seeds or are there others?

Tags: fruit-trees, shrubs, vines

I'm making an app and for this app i need to know from which things you can grow non herbaceous plants from.

I am looking for general terms.

For instance, a coconut tree and an avocado tree van both be grown from a nut.

An apple tree, pineapple tree, and banana tree can all 3 be grown from seeds.

Are there any other trees/vines/shrubs that produce edibles of which propagation does not fall in the nut or seed category? For instance are there trees that produce spores?

Thank you

EDIT: Here is my full propagation method list.

```
    SEED,
    BULB_OR_CORM,
    RHIZOME,
    TUBER,
    NUT,
    SPORES,
    MYCELIUM,
//    ----ARTIFICIAL PROPAGATION---- 
    CUTTING,
    GROUND_LAYERING,
    AIR_LAYERING,
    DIVISION,
    BUDDING_OR_GRAFTING
```

Comment: Are you wanting to know only about plants that produce edible  fruits/seeds/nuts?

Comment: @Bamboo, yes. And now that i think of it i would also like to know if there are any herbaceous plants that can grow from a nut. I take it peanuts plants grow from nuts?

Comment: A couple of things - pineapples grow from a herbaceous plant, not a tree, Peanuts are "ground nuts", not true nuts, and do not grow on trees; they're actually seeds planted by the plant itself - see here for info http://bioweb.uwlax.edu/bio203/s2012/steinmet_vero/reproduction.htm

Comment: Would you consider rooted cuttings a means of propagation for your app?

Comment: @Jurp, I have cutting, listed as an artificial propagation method. If you want you can take a look at the full list of all selectable propagations, Both natural and artificial. If you think i've missed one please let me know. I will add the list to my post now.

Comment: @Jurp, about your other remark, I think i'll put ground nut and true nut under the same denominer. To an expert they are different, but my website will probably be used allot by regular (amateur) gardeners and to them a nuts a nut ;)

Comment: Well actually, a peanut is a legume, like peas and lentils...

Comment: You perhaps might also bear in mind that fruit  producing trees and bushes do not necessarily come true from seed -  tomatoes, chili nd  apples being prime examples. That is why some fruit bearing plants are propagated from cuttings, sometimes grafted onto a different rootstock (apples for instance)

Comment: @Bamboo, what do you mean. Don't tomatoes grow from seed? And if apples don't grow  from seeds then why do they have seeds in the center? Or do you mean that certain varieties can only be grown from cuttings? Thank you

Comment: Let's talk apples - you can certainly plant the seeds from an apple,but what grows may be  50 feet tall with thorns and rather unpleasant apples, once they appear anyway, which will take years. So yes, it's an apple tree, but not a known variety and it may not produce tasty fruits. With chili peppers if you save seed from a pepper you grew yourself outdoors, what grows the following year may not be the variety you kept the seeds from. As well, any plant that is an F1 hybrid usually produces sterile seeds. tomatoes can be grown reliably from seed, if they have not been allowed to crosspollinate

Comment: And commercially, bananas are propagated using tissue culture.

Comment: @Bamboo, thank you for your elaborate answer. It reminds me of a video i've watched explaining that apple tree flowers have an enzyme that destroy pollen grains coming from other flowers on the same tree. Thats why you need 2 apple trees with different DNA which will always result in a new variety when crossed.